# How to access MUI TextField styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create styled component using styled() function and 'div'. I want to apply styles for div from Material UI's TextField component (border, hover, etc.). Is it possible to access those styles in theme component?

What I am trying to achieve is to have wrapper that looks exactly like material ui TextArea  and have hover effect with pointer events, but the main difference that it can host any children inside it (React.ReactNode) instead of text.

Comment: TextField is not single component. It containes several components that act like 1. For example: InputLabel, FormHelperText, input, FormControl... Also not everything is just css there, there is also functionality via js

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is creating a custom component and styling it exactly the same way as Mui Textfield, which should not be too difficult. Im not sure, if there is a way to access MUI component styles. You could inspect browser and look through Styles to get an idea of how TextField is styled.